# Connection:Keep-Alive missing from Header for Android versions 3.x and lower; Fiddler reporting Request Missing required Host Header

Tags: java, android, jsp, tomcat, header

Platform: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Web Server: Apache Tomcat 7.0

I did a clean install of Tomcat 7.0 and nothing has been changed, other than adding my own web application, which consists of a few JSP pages, and enabling SSL.  It's very minimal and designed to test this problem with Android versions 3.x and lower.

For these versions, I have confirmed the the Android browser and Dolphin browser 9.0.3 both DO NOT have the Connection Request Header, never mind about Connection:Keep-Alive.  That is, there is no persistent HTTP Connection.  However, Opera Mobile 12.0.3 DOES contain the Connection:Keep-Alive Request Header.

The related problem to this is when using SSL, the HTTP Proxy, Fiddler, is reporting

> HTTP/1.1 Request was missing the required HOST header

The differences I see from Opera and Android/Dolphin browsers is the former contains User-Agent: Opera/9.80..., Connection:Keep-Alive, and Host:{Web Server} and the latter contains only Host: {Web Server}.  I see this information in a Fiddler entry that is titled "Tunnel To" for the Host column.  I do NOT see this type of entry for the Opera browser, only for Android/Dolphin browsers.

Again, I want to make this clear that this problem is ONLY occuring on Android 3.x and lower versions.  iOS is fine.  All major desktop browsers are fine.  Android 4.x is fine.

Does anyone have any insight into what could be the problem?

Thank you.